# IsolatedStorageSettings WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

I have one problem which I cannot resolve (at least I didn't found solution yet...) I wanted to add data into IsolatedStorageSettings in WP8. My goal is to check if there are settings already in there, but when I want to check I get an exception which I cannot resolve.

```
    private IsolatedStorageSettings appSettings = new IsolatedStorageSettings();

                private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        //correct this part
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty((string)appSettings["ICE1"])|| 
            String.IsNullOrEmpty((string)appSettings["ICE2"]) || 
            String.IsNullOrEmpty((string)appSettings["ICE3"]) || 
            String.IsNullOrEmpty((string)appSettings["address"]) || 
            String.IsNullOrEmpty((string)appSettings["fullName"]))
        {
        appSettings.Add("fullName", fullName.Text);
        appSettings.Save();

        appSettings.Add("address", address.Text);
        appSettings.Save();
        if (Regex.IsMatch(prefix1.Text, "^+\\d{2,3}") && Regex.IsMatch(number1.Text, "d{6,10}"))
        {
            appSettings.Add("ICE1", prefix1.Text + number1.Text);
            appSettings.Save();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid prefix number, please use +01 and for numbers only 0-9...");
        }
        if (Regex.IsMatch(prefix2.Text, "^+\\d{2,3}") && Regex.IsMatch(number2.Text, "d{6,10}"))
        {
            appSettings.Add("ICE2", prefix2.Text + number2.Text);
            appSettings.Save();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid prefix number, please use +01 and for numbers only 0-9...");
        }
        if (Regex.IsMatch(prefix2.Text, "^+\\d{2,3}") && Regex.IsMatch(number2.Text, "d{6,10}"))
        {
            appSettings.Add("ICE3", prefix2.Text + number2.Text);
            appSettings.Save();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid prefix number, please use +01 and for numbers only 0-9...");
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Your information is saved...!");
        }
        else
        {
        //
            appSettings["fullName"] = fullName.Text;
            appSettings.Save();

            appSettings["address"] = address.Text;
            appSettings.Save();
            if (Regex.IsMatch(prefix1.Text, "^+\\d{2,3}") && Regex.IsMatch(number1.Text, "d{6,10}"))
            {
                appSettings["ICE1"]= prefix1.Text + number1.Text;
                appSettings.Save();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid prefix number, please use +01 and for numbers only 0-9...");
            }
            if (Regex.IsMatch(prefix2.Text, "^+\\d{2,3}") && Regex.IsMatch(number2.Text, "d{6,10}"))
            {
                appSettings["ICE2"] = prefix2.Text + number2.Text;
                appSettings.Save();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid prefix number, please use +01 and for numbers only 0-9...");
            }
            if (Regex.IsMatch(prefix2.Text, "^+\\d{2,3}") && Regex.IsMatch(number2.Text, "d{6,10}"))
            {
                appSettings["ICE3"] = prefix3.Text + number3.Text;
                appSettings.Save();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid prefix number, please use +01 and for numbers only 0-9...");
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Your information is saved...!");
        }
```

Can someone explain how IsolatedStorageWorks?
How can I correct this part because this is causing the problem:

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty((string)appSettings["ICE1"])|| 
            String.IsNullOrEmpty((string)appSettings["ICE2"]) || 
            String.IsNullOrEmpty((string)appSettings["ICE3"]) || 
            String.IsNullOrEmpty((string)appSettings["address"]) || 
            String.IsNullOrEmpty((string)appSettings["fullName"]))
```

Do I need to do appSettings.Save() every each time when I wish to add the data or update-it...?

I also have another problem of getting data from IsolatedStorageSettings:

```
     public WindowsPhoneControl2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    string ice1;
    string ice2;
    string ice3;

    PhoneCallTask ptask = new PhoneCallTask();

    private void Image_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        ptask.PhoneNumber = ice1;
        ptask.DisplayName = "Contact person 1";
        ptask.Show();
    }

    private void Image_Tap_1(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        ptask.PhoneNumber = ice2;
        ptask.DisplayName = "Contact person 2";
        ptask.Show();
    }

    private void Image_Tap_2(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        ptask.PhoneNumber = ice3;
        ptask.DisplayName = "Contact person 3";
        ptask.Show();
    }

    private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsolatedStorageSettings appSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
        appSettings.Contains("fullName");

        fullName.Text = (string)appSettings["fullName"];
        address.Text = (string)appSettings["address"];
        phone1.Text = (string)appSettings["ICE1"];
        phone2.Text = (string)appSettings["ICE1"];
        phone3.Text = (string)appSettings["ICE1"];

        ice1 = phone1.Text;
        ice2 = phone2.Text;
        ice3 = phone3.Text;
    }
```

especially this part which is supposed to get data from dictionary:

```
            fullName.Text = (string)appSettings["fullName"];
        address.Text = (string)appSettings["address"];
        phone1.Text = (string)appSettings["ICE1"];
        phone2.Text = (string)appSettings["ICE1"];
        phone3.Text = (string)appSettings["ICE1"];
```

Comment: What is the exception that you get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IsolatedStorage Settins works like a [dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).
I think you should change:

```
private IsolatedStorageSettings userSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
```

I would rather use method Contains to check whether key is there:

```
if (userSettings.Contains("ICE1")|| 
        userSettings.Contains("ICE2") || 
        userSettings.Contains("ICE3") || 
        userSettings.Contains("address") || 
        userSettings.Contains("fullName"))
```

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings.save%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), Settings are saved when the Application is closed or you call Save:

```
Data written to the IsolatedStorageSettings object is saved when the application that
uses the class is closed. If you want your application to write to isolated storage 
immediately, you can call the Save method in application code.
```

**EDIT**
Sample code to play with:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
  private IsolatedStorageSettings userSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

  public MainPage()
  {
     InitializeComponent();

     bool isKey = userSettings.Contains("anyKey"); //toggle break point at this line
     userSettings.Add("anyKey", "myValue");
     isKey = userSettings.Contains("anyKey");
     string value = (string)userSettings["anyKey"];
  }
}
```

Comment: but if this field is not initiated, it doesn't exist. that would mean that userSettings would have null value. According to the MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc614991%28v=vs.95%29.aspx it would give me an exception of null key value. What then?

Comment: would it be wise to use userSettings.Count > 0 before testing a specific field in dictionary?

Comment: ApplicationSettings belongs to your App: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402541(v=vs.105).aspx and you use ApplicationSettings Property http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings.applicationsettings(v=vs.95).aspx to initiate the field (my first line of code above private ...) Method Contains (which you ask) will return you bool value depending if key exists, or throw exception if you enter wrong name od the key. If you know exact name of the key you can check if it exist in the dictionary.

Comment: I've also added a sample code - run in debug mode, set breakpoint at bool isKey ... then step forward and look how usersettings are changing and other variables.

Comment: Thanks Romasz, I will modify my code and try what you suggested. I will test it when I get home from work. cheers

Comment: Hi Romasz, this actually worked. I have checked count and after that did another check by using contains method that you suggested. Thanks! Now I need only to change some code for getting data from IsolatedStorageSettings because on emulator it worked flawlessly with current code, but on my WP8 device it doesn't.

Comment: The problematic code is:             
            fullName.Text = (string)appSettings["fullName"];
            address.Text = (string)appSettings["address"];
            phone1.Text = (string)appSettings["ICE1"];
            phone2.Text = (string)appSettings["ICE1"];
            phone3.Text = (string)appSettings["ICE1"];

Comment: @dovla091 There can be many errors, even not connected with IsolSettings. 1) if you try do those lines before InitializeContent(), 2) if you try read keys, before you add them. You can use such code: bool isOK = appSettings.TryGetValue<string>("ICE1", out phone1.Text). The best way is to debug it and see where exception occurs.

Comment: Well basically I have inserted data into IsolSettings on one WindowsPhoneControl1, and try to get them on another (WindowsPhoneCotrol2). I have added lines above... but not sure which part is causing a problem...

Comment: Well - I cannot help you without seeing the code. I think that if you use debugger, step over and see exceptions you should be able to find it and correnct it.

Comment: actually I found another way by using IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["fullName"] as string; not sure why didn't worked with previous code, but never the less it is fixed. Thank you. Btw I have noticed that in emulator code is working just fine, but on device it is totally different story. The reason for that is, emulator clears keys and values from storage each time and that is why I haven't had a problem until I transferred app to the device.

Answer (score 0):

IsolatedStorageSetting stores data in key/value pair. If there exist a key there must would be a value regarding this key. so just simpley check whether key exist in setting or not using `if(settings.Contains("YourKey"))`. If the condition true do your work. Thanks